# Moving an external hard drive to a fresh install

Tags: hardware, permissions, storage, 64-bit

I use a pi4 with 32-bit raspbian and a USB drive with an ext4 partition as a NAS. I want to upgrade the pi4 to 64-bit through a fresh install.

If I reinstall raspbian with the same user/pw, will my permissions be ok to simply reattach the drive? Do I need to alter permissions first?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? You have nothing to lose. It depends on how you are using the drive. Frankly you are unlikely to notice any difference between 32 &64 bit - also Bookworm is likely to be released in the next couple of months.